# Participle clause

Tags: participle-clauses

I want to mean that "I studied in a University and I majored in Accounting", but I'm wondering what should I write with the participle clause.

> Graduated from ABC University and majored in Accounting
>
> Or
>
> Graduating from ABC University and majoring in Accounting
>
> Or
>
> Having graduated from ABC University and majored in Accounting

Which sentence is the most correct one?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you speak about your graduation from the university as a *completed* action (having graduated...), the part with *majoring* will most likely have a different verb tense (not a participle), since that (if I understand it right) continued while you studied, before you've graduated:

> Having graduated from ABC University where I majored in Accounting...

Comment: can you please help me check my writing's grammar and word choice errors? I have no one to ask.